# Unique Contact in Report

Tags: reporting

I need to have a tabular report of all contacts who are member of any campaign. I dont want any contact to appear twice in the report.

Is it possible?

Comment: Post your approach whatever you have tried so far. You already know [ask]

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible out of the box with Salesforce reports: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrYLAA0

You'll likely have to use SOQL using GROUP BY to achieve this.